# How to display these 5 bar plot in the same workspace?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, bar-chart

This is the dataframe I'm working with

```
> Age_Time
# A tibble: 268 x 2
   Age     Time      
   <chr>   <chr>     
 1 [18,24[ 1-5 hours 
 2 [10,18[ 1-5 hours 
 3 [18,24[ >10 hours 
 4 [18,24[ 5-10 hours
 5 [18,24[ 5-10 hours
 6 [24,34[ 1-5 hours 
 7 [18,24[ 5-10 hours
 8 [18,24[ 5-10 hours
 9 [24,34[ 0 hours   
10 [18,24[ 5-10 hours
# ... with 258 more rows
> str(head(Age_Time))
tibble [6 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Age : chr [1:6] "[18,24[" "[10,18[" "[18,24[" "[18,24[" ...
 $ Time: chr [1:6] "1-5 hours" "1-5 hours" ">10 hours" "5-10 hours" ...
```

I made 5 barplots as follows seperately and I want to put them in the same workspace so that they get displayed together

```
Age_time=Survey[3:4]

Time1=Age_time %>%
      filter(Time=="0 hours")
b1 <- barplot(table(Time1$Age),col=colors,ylim=c(0,10),main = "No time spent on Social Media")
text(b1[,1],table(Time1$Age)-1,table(Time1$Age))
Time2=Age_time %>%
      filter(Time== "<1 hours")
b2 <- barplot(table(Time2$Age),col=colors,ylim=c(0,20),main="Less than an hour spent on Social Media")
text(b2[,1],table(Time2$Age)-1,table(Time2$Age))

Time3=Age_time %>%
      filter(Time =="1-5 hours")
b3 <- barplot(table(Time3$Age),col=colors,ylim=c(0,100),main="1 to 5 hours on Social Media")
text(b3[,1],table(Time3$Age)-1,table(Time3$Age))

Time4=Age_time %>%
  filter(Time =="5-10 hours")
b4 <- barplot(table(Time4$Age),col=colors,ylim=c(0,90),main="5 to 10 hours on Social Media")
text(b4[,1],table(Time4$Age)-1,table(Time4$Age))

Time5=Age_time %>%
  filter(Time ==">10 hours")
b5 <- barplot(table(Time5$Age),col=colors,ylim=c(0,40),main="More than 10 hours on Social Media")
text(b5[,1],table(Time5$Age)-1,table(Time5$Age))
```

I don't mind changing  the whole code and use ggplot for example as long as I get the results I want in the end which is obtaining the 5 figures side by side **( not with shared axis )**

Comment: You can use `patchwork` `(b1|b2|b3)/(b4|b5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing this before the first `barplot`

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
```

This will place all 5 `barplot`s side by side in the same plot window